How to allow users to provide their own child classes in a factory design pattern in c++?
I am building a c++ project that will allow users to essentially model and create their own fleet of cars.
Right now, the approach I have in mind is a Car Factory Class that will implement all of the car classes/car child classes objects. However, at run time, how would I have the child class objects declared and instantiated without hard-coding them into the factory class?
For example, the user must provider a toml config file with various parameters. Now, I can have information like the name, the file path, and other aspects of the child car class.
The goal is:

Car Factory -> default car class (if none are provided)
Car Factory -> default car class -> child car class, like a Mercedes or Honda

The one issue I am having is that when I want to extend the factory interface to the user such that they can provider their own implementation of the car classes, I am stuck in being able to visualize how to approach it.
Another issue I am having is how to approach having the user actually offer the user-defined classes. Do I use DLLs implementation with a plug in system and load it all at run time? Do I have an abstract factory class the user then implements and places the file into the project folder along with their implemented child classes?
I would appreciate it if someone could give me advice on how to tackle users being able to provider user-defined code and have it seamlessly integrate properly. I have read a lot of approaches, and I am trying not to get information overload and implement design patterns/DLLS w a plug in system/ other avenues without really understand it for what it is and its uses.
Thank you.

I'm confused. Why is Mercedes or Honda a child class of Car? In other words: why do you even bother with inheritance? Just don't. Problem solved.

You wrote "will allow users to essentially model and create their own fleet of cars." - fine. But what do you expect from "users"? Are users other devs in your team who know C++, have access to the code and shall be able to write new C++ classses directly in your project? Or are users only allowed to extend the mentioned config file? Or are you having users in mind who get a compiled library of your C++ project and shall be able to write their own C++ classes afterwards, which then gets linked with the existing lib? Please clarify your requirements first!

How does a fleet of Honda's behave differently from a fleet of generic cars? You only need child classes if there is a difference in behavior (and that difference is relevant for your application).

Do you want the users of your factory to add subclasses at compile-time so that the factory can return also objects of that user-defined subclasses ?
In this case you need two more things in your factory:

the factory function needs to be parameterized, i.e. a parameter tells what class/subclass to instantiate (see GoF page 111), for example:
my_car = factory.make(""); // default car
their_car = factory.make("Mercedes");


the factory also needs a class registration mechanism to add the new subclasses:
factory.register("Mercedes", Mercedes::make); // UserClass::make() would be a static function called by the factory

The main thing to decide is whether the use of an unregistered parameter value should simply return an object of the default class, or if it should raise an exception.


The constraint is that the factory returns a Car so the caller cannot use all the jingle bells and additional functions that a Mercedes would add to the basic Car interface, unless doing dynamic casting (but better stay with a polymorphic design).
If you want users to extend the classes at runtime, i.e. feeding your executable with their own dynamic libraries, etc, you'd come to a terribly complex and non-portable solution. In this case you should rather think of another, flatter design, probably something looking more like the entity-component-system, using runtime configuration of components and assembly of entities.
By the way, before building a design that relies on deep class hierarchies, take also a look at entity-component-system, as it is based on composition over inheritance and offers greater flexibility.

There's nothing about the mechanism you described that doesn't work with runtime (dynamic library) extensions.  In fact, that's exactly how Microsoft COM works.  (Neither the only one, nor even the first, but one of the most pervasive examples)

@BenVoigt Sure. I didn't say it's not feasible. But are DLLs  portable? And since it's a C++ question: aren't there strong constraints if you want to share classes between your main executable and the user's custom dll ?

Oh certainly there are limitations on mixing DLL code built with different compilers.  But none of those are any different between Factory creation of objects vs any other algorithm you might want to place in a DLL.

Favor composition and delegation over inheritance asks you to consider delegating by hand what inheritance is making easy to write, just not easy to use.
If you provide an interface that you own, that they could implement, what exactly are you losing? Because you're gaining a lot more flexibility.

Firstly, consider composition over inheritance per other questions. I'll come back to this point.

The one issue I am having is that when I want to extend the factory interface to the user such that they can provider their own implementation of the car classes, I am stuck in being able to visualize how to approach it.

The developer of the class should provide the factory for the class. You can't expect the Mercedes factory to turn out Fords.
What I think you've run into is the following problem:

the factory does substantial work that would otherwise be in the constructor (normal case for a factory)

normally the subclass constructor would call the parent constructor, but now that doesn't work so well: either you duplicate the work of the other factory in the child factory, or you move the work back into the constructor

by definition, you don't know what work the subclass constructors are going to do

the object has significant sub-objects, but at the same time is NOT some sort of entity component system


I'm also a little unclear as to who's actually consuming all these car classes and who's ordering their creation?

Do I use DLLs implementation with a plug in system and load it all at run time? Do I have an abstract factory class the user then implements and places the file into the project folder along with their implemented child classes?

I don't know, what do you want to ship?
If you want to ship compiled code only, and your code is the code calling all the various car constructors, then I think you have no choice but to build a plugin system.
On the other hand, if your car library is being consumed by another application, which is also providing the extra cars, then there's no problem. Your code sits off to the side and it's up to the caller to instantiate MercedesFactory() etc.
I would suggest moving to a dependency injection approach. That's for C#, but you can do similar things in C++, except you don't have reflection. You could also look at "Java Beans", which was a similar generic construction system.
Designing a library so that it can be subclassed easily is quite hard. Now we come back to composition over inheritance: does Car need to be subclassible as a whole, or can we extract its behaviors? Maybe it could be a template Car? As it stands, the question is very vague about why any of this exists.
